# Does Twilio whatsApp Business API provides feature to schedule a message or media ? I couldn't find anything related to it in the docs

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to integrate Twilio WhatsApp API with my application, one of my use-cases requires scheduling WhatsApp messages. I am working on node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there isn't a built in scheduler. You would need to use an external job scheduler to schedule your tasks.

For example:
[4 ways to schedule Node.js code](https://www.twilio.com/blog/4-ways-to-schedule-node-code)

Google Apps also has a scheduler which is very simple to use.